# Html.Actionlink not providing both parameters to Controller - nullable int exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, actionlink

I am trying to pass two parameters into a controller to allow a simple Create process to happen.

My actionlink is:

```
Html.ActionLink("New EB", "Create", "Erroneous", new { id = Model.Id, customerId = Model.Customer.Id }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

My Controller is:

```
[Route("{customerId}/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Create(int id, int customerId)
    {
        if (customerId == 0)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customerId);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var viewModel = new CreateErroneousBillViewModel
        {
            Id = id,
            CustomerId = customer.Id,
        };

        return View("CreateErroneousBillForm", viewModel);
    }
```

However when clicking on the action link the url onl provides the first id and not the second like such:

```
http://localhost:65339/Erroneous/Create/24/
```

Where 24 is the Id of customer

whereas I think it should be providing something like

```
http://localhost:65339/Erroneous/Create/24/1
```

Where 1 is the Id

Any help appreciated, have been scratching my head over this for a while now.

Edit:

I have also tried setting absolute values to eliminate null values coming from the model

```
Html.ActionLink("New EB", "Create", "Erroneous", new { id = 1, customerId = 24 }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

This also did not work.

Comment: are you sure  Model.Customer.Id  is not null?

Comment: I have tried changing the link to include absolute values and still suffer the same issue. I.e  id =1, customerId = 24.   I've added this as part of my original question. Thanks!

Comment: your question is valid when i use conventional routing and attribute routing  i get expected result /24/1

Comment: can you also add RouteConfig code?

Comment: Seems that you need custom routing with `{controller}/{action}/{id}/{customerId}` which id & customerId are optional URL parameters. I can provide explanation if `RouteConfig` code also included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this.

I was making a silly error and changing the wrong ActionLink so the one that we were clicking in the UI turned out to be completely the wrong one.

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

This is how would I do this:
First of all remove this dataAnotation [Route("{customerId}/{id}")]
and then when you call Html.ActionLink("New EB", "Create", "Erroneous", new { id = 1, customerId = 24 }, htmlAttributes: null)
the link would look like:
http://localhost:65339/Erroneous/Create?id=1&customerId=24
I hope my answer will help you, have a nice day!

Comment: Removing the AttributeRouting didnt change anything and the URL is still showing as http://localhost:65339/Erroneous/Create/24 :( Thanks